# Spring JPA Query to find all strings that are part of a query string

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I would like to explain my problem with an example. In mongodb I have a String column. Now I want to list all strings in that column which are part of my query string.

For example if my query string is "This is my test string".

My ideal results would be

"This", 
"This is", 
"This is my",
"is my",
"is my test", 
"This is my test", 
"This is my test string" etc..,

In mysql I know "%Like%" would handle. I tried "Like" in mongo JPA but no luck.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Since mongodb is a document database, I suppose by "column", you mean "field". You want to search for all the field values that matches "This" or "is" or "my" or "test" or "string"?

Comment: Yes I meant field. I want to search for all values that make part of the test sentence. Please read the example.

Comment: What does MongoDB have to do with JPA? "Mongo JPA" is not a thing.

Answer (score 0):

As JB mentioned, there is no Mongo JPA, but I assume you want a similar behavior as what Spring Data JPA does for you which is what Spring Data MongoDB does.

To do so, you need to use In and a collection of the string part of your query. So you will need to break your string first.

In your repository, use Spring Data's query DSL with In i.e:

```
public interface YourDocumentRepository extends MongoRepository<YourDocument, ClassTypeOfYourId> {

  public List<YourDocument> findByNameIn(string[] text);

}
```

If the name of your string field is `superDuper`, the example would be:

```
public List<YourDocument> findBySuperDuperIn(string[] text);
```

You should adjust. For more detail, take a look at [the reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords) or some example [here](https://www.baeldung.com/queries-in-spring-data-mongodb).

Comment: This is not what I wanted. for example "is my test" is not containing the string "This is my test string". You kind of said opposite of the requirement. I tested this already.

Comment: I misunderstood. I re-adjusted